# Why is Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER 9,007,199,254,740,991 and not 9,007,199,254,740,992?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, integer, ieee-754

ECMAScript 6's `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` supposedly represents the maximum numerical value JavaScript can store before issues arise with floating point precision. However it's a requirement that the number 1 added to this value must also be representable as a `Number`.

> #### `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`
>
> *NOTE The value of `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is the largest integer `n` such that `n` and `n + 1` are both exactly representable as a `Number` value.*
>
> The value of `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is `9007199254740991 (2^53−1)`.
>
> – [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://people.mozilla.org/%7Ejorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-number.max_safe_integer)

The JavaScript consoles of Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE11 can all safely perform calculations with the number 9,007,199,254,740,992. Some tests:

```js
// Valid
Math.pow(2, 53)                         // 9007199254740992
9007199254740991 + 1                    // 9007199254740992
9007199254740992 - 1                    // 9007199254740991
9007199254740992 / 2                    // 4503599627370496
4503599627370496 * 2                    // 9007199254740992
parseInt('20000000000000', 16)          // 9007199254740992
parseInt('80000000000', 32)             // 9007199254740992
9007199254740992 - 9007199254740992     // 0
9007199254740992 == 9007199254740991    // false
9007199254740992 == 9007199254740992    // true

// Erroneous
9007199254740992 + 1                    // 9007199254740992
9007199254740993 + ""                   // "9007199254740992"
9007199254740992 == 9007199254740993    // true
```

Why is it a requirement that `n + 1` must also be representable as a `Number`? Why does failing this make the value *unsafe*?

Comment: Maybe because `2^53 - 1` is the last value which can be accurately represented - `2^53` will give the same value as `2^53 + 1` ("Stolen" from https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read#leanpub-auto-numbers)

Comment: The numbers start from `0`.. maybe this is the reason.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I would say its because while `Math.pow(2, 53)` is the largest directly representable integer, its *unsafe* in that its also the first value who's representation is also an approximation of another value:

`9007199254740992 == 9007199254740993 // true`

In contrast to `Math.pow(2, 53) - 1`:

`9007199254740991 == 9007199254740993 // false`

Comment: I guess `99007199254740992` is unsafe by proxy, and not necessarily an unsafe number when you know that that is definitely the value you're wanting to use.

Answer (score 4):

I also have the same concern about the question. <JavaScript: The Definitive Guide> said the safe range is `-2^53~2^53`(Including boundary values) while <You don't know JavaScript> said the range is`-2^53+1~2^53-1`.

Finally, I found the Correct interpretation in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger

It said, the "safe"means :

1. can be exactly represented as an IEEE-754 double precision number, and
2. whose IEEE-754 representation cannot be the result of rounding any other integer to fit the IEEE-754 representation.

So `2^53` is not a safe integer because :
it can be exactly represented in IEEE-754, but the integer `2^53 + 1` can't be directly represented in IEEE-754 but instead rounds to `2^53` under round-to-nearest and round-to-zero rounding.

Answer (score 2):

the only number which is in close proximity of another
when compared with its next number shows true

```
9007199254740992 == 9007199254740993
true
9007199254740993 == 9007199254740994
false
9007199254740991 == 9007199254740992
false
9007199254740997 == 9007199254740998
false
```

Comment: Your "false" results are all crossing across multiple-of-2 boundary, with the odd number being the lower one.  If you compare an even number and the next higher number, like `2^53 + 4` and `2^53 + 5`, you will find them equal in IEEE754 double precision.