# Natural logarithm e === 1

Tags: javascript, math

```
function a (n){return (1+1/n) ** n }
```

why

```
a(9007199254740991) === 7.389056098930647
```

but if the n > 9007199254740991 the function will return 1 ?

https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6%E5%B8%B8%E6%95%B0)

Comment: Related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380364/why-is-number-max-safe-integer-9-007-199-254-740-991-and-not-9-007-199-254-740-9

Comment: Try the function without the `** n` and see if you can find anything interesting.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy  Do you know How the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`9007199254740991` is the maximal safe integer for use in ECMAScript computations (also predefined as the constant `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`).

This is the limitation of JavaScript's math, doing computations on double-precision floating point numbers. If you exceed this constant, there can be unpredictable results at any point, like i.e. `9007199254740992 == 9007199254740993` evaluating to `true`.

Here is the [documentation of `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

Comment: why there are  maximal safe integer,what's means safe?

Comment: Shortly - because of in JavaScript every number is a `double` and there is rounding involved in computations with "unsafe" numbers, which lead pretty much to things like `x + 1` equals to `x + 2`, which can not be correct. I have posted a link to a documentation which explains this well.