# Math.pow gives wrong result

Tags: javascript, pow

I was trying to repeat a character *N* times, and came across the `Math.pow` function.

But when I use it in the console, the results don't make any sense to me:

`Math.pow(10,15) - 1` provides the correct result **999999999999999**

But why does `Math.pow(10,16) - 1` provide **10000000000000000**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are producing results which exceed the [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) value, and so they are not accurate any more up to the unit.

This is related to the fact that JavaScript uses 64-bit floating point representation for numbers, and so in practice you only have about 16 (decimal) digits of precision.

Since the introduction of [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) in EcmaScript, you can get an accurate result with that data type, although it cannot be used in combination with `Math.pow`. Instead you can use the `**` operator.

See how the use of number and bigint (with the `n` suffix) differ:

```
10  ** 16  - 1  // == 10000000000000000
10n ** 16n - 1n // ==  9999999999999999n
```

Comment: Might mention that there are [arbitrary precision libraries](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/) out there.

Comment: Another useful link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380364/why-is-number-max-safe-integer-9-007-199-254-740-991-and-not-9-007-199-254-740-9

Answer (score 0):

Unlike many other programming languages, JavaScript does not define different types of numbers, like integers, short, long, floating-point etc.

JavaScript numbers are always stored as double-precision floating-point numbers, following the international IEEE 754 standard.

This format stores numbers in 64 bits, where the number (the fraction) is stored in bits 0 to 51, the exponent in bits 52 to 62, and the sign-in bit 63:

Integers (numbers without a period or exponent notation) are accurate up to 15 digits.